# after creating an execution in twilio flow, how can I exchange messages with the flow using the execution through the Rest API trigger

Tags: twilio, backend

from the following [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/execution?display=embedded&code-sample=code-create-an-execution-with-custom-parameters&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=4.x) I learned how to create and manage executions in a Twilio flow but I don't know how to send end user's messages to Twilio flow execution and receive the replies before sending it to the end user, take note that I want to be the middle man between Twilio flow and the user

Comment: Can you explain what information you'd like to receive? You can either use the HTTP widget to send information you gathered during the flow to your endpoints, or [fetch a single execution](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution#fetch-a-single-execution) to read the steps of the flow. But you won't be able to manipulate the flow execution.